# Input field for filtering does not react to button-click input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, kendo-grid

So, I am using angular with a kendo grid with filtering options. To filter, one must write something in the input field. But I wanted the user to have a possibility to click on a button which automatically fills the input field with some text.

```
 <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
        <input placeholder="Filter"  (input)="onFilter($event.target.value)" id="filter" value="" type="textbox" />
 </ng-template>
```

So when a user clicks some button it fills the input field with text like this:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Filter")).value= "New York";
```

The input field is filled with this text, but it doesnt filter. On the other hand, when I manually fill the input field, it is filtering. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change/input event is not getting triggered because you updated the input programatically.
You can use `CustomEvent` to tell the listeners that something has been changed.

Exapmle

Html:

```
<input placeholder="Filter"  (input)="onFilter($event.target)" id="filter" value="" type="textbox" />
<button (click)="buttonClick()">Click</button>
```

Ts:

```
   buttonClick() {
     const inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("filter")
     inputElement.value = "New York"

     const evt = new CustomEvent("input")
     inputElement.dispatchEvent(evt)
  }

  onFilter(ev) {
    console.log("click - ", ev.value)
  }
```